How to use django TemporaryUploadedFile multiple times?
I am trying to create several records in django from a TemporaryUploadedFile object, due to the nature of this, when wanting to create more records, I get the error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpoz8_c7i3.upload. jpg'.
I already tried to override the classes, to set delete=False of tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile, but I still get the error.
Django Version = 4.1.3
Python Version = 3.8.18
from django.core.files.uploadhandler import FileUploadHandler, TemporaryFileUploadHandler
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import UploadedFile
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files import temp as tempfile
class CustomTemporaryFileUploadHandler(TemporaryFileUploadHandler):
    """
    Upload handler that streams data into a temporary file.
    """

    def new_file(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Create the file object to append to as data is coming in.
        """
        super().new_file(*args, **kwargs)
        self.file = CustomTemporaryUploadedFile(
            self.file_name, self.content_type, 0, self.charset, self.content_type_extra
        )

    def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
        self.file.write(raw_data)

    def file_complete(self, file_size):
        self.file.seek(0)
        self.file.size = file_size
        return self.file

    def upload_interrupted(self):
        if hasattr(self, "file"):
            temp_location = self.file.temporary_file_path()
            try:
                self.file.close()
                os.remove(temp_location)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass


class CustomTemporaryUploadedFile(UploadedFile):
    """
    A file uploaded to a temporary location (i.e. stream-to-disk).
    """

    def __init__(self, name, content_type, size, charset, content_type_extra=None):
        _, ext = os.path.splitext(name)
        file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(
            suffix=".upload" + ext,
            dir=settings.FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR,
            delete=False
        )
        super().__init__(file, name, content_type, size, charset, content_type_extra)

    def temporary_file_path(self):
        """Return the full path of this file."""
        return self.file.name

    def close(self):
        try:
            return self.file.close()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            # The file was moved or deleted before the tempfile could unlink
            # it. Still sets self.file.close_called and calls
            # self.file.file.close() before the exception.
            pass


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

maybe better code where you trying to create several records - maybe this part needs changes instead of creating own class TemporaryFileUploadHandler. It can be The XY Problem
